# How to delete product custom option value programmatically in Magento?

Tags: magento, product

I want to remove a custom-option value for a product. Please help me.

Comment: Just so you know, there is a whole site dedicated to Magneto here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ,you want delete  option of product custom then used below code.

Where $valueId= option ID

```
$optionValue=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value')->load($valueId);
$optionValue->delete();
```